# Can't use a Neo4j VM deployed in Azure

Tags: azure, neo4j

I'm trying to connect to my Neo4j VM but I have the following error:

```
SessionExpired: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver
```

What can I do ?

Comment: I solved it, first you have to enter "neo4j" with username and password. Next you change your password and it will work

Comment: Agreed. Your first login use username: neo4j and pswd: neo4j. It will then prompt you to enter another password. The url should be http://{ip}:7474